# Add UIImagePickerController to a kivy-ios-app (Python)

Tags: python, ios, kivy, uiimagepickercontroller, photo

I want to access my images/photo gallery on an iOS device from a kivy application.
Kivy has no native way implemented to do this, so I'm trying to solve it with  [kivy/pyobjus](https://github.com/kivy/pyobjus)
where I can use the UIImagePickerController (from Apples UIKit).

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from pyobjus import autoclass, protocol



class TestApp(App):

    ui = Builder.load_file("main.kv")
    def build(self):
        return self.ui

    def imagePicker(self):
        UIImagePickerController = autoclass('UIImagePickerController')
        self.picker = UIImagePickerController.alloc().init()
        self.picker.delegate = self
        self.picker.sourceType = 0

        @protocol('UIImagePickerControllerDelegate')
        def imagePickerControllerDidFinish(self, image):
           print("ABC")
```

The ui is just a button, which calls the imagePicker function.
I have three questions on this code:

1. How can I display the imagePicker?
2. When I'm using imagePicker.delegate = self, the App crashes because

   > [...] delegate, but there is no @protocol methods declared.

   But I declared a protocol with "@protocol('UIImagePickerControllerDelegate')"
   So why it won't use my declared protocol? (I tried also to add the "UIImagePickerControllerDelegate" in [the protocols.py from pyobjus](https://github.com/kivy/pyobjus/blob/master/pyobjus/protocols.py). This didn't solved the problem)
3. If the protocol will work, it is the correct way to use the "imagePickerControllerDidFinish(self, image)" method to access the image?

Comment: Answer to the 2nd question: self.picker.delegate = self.picker